# Go program not statically linked using 1.4.2

Tags: go, static-linking

Trying to build a statically linked version of a go program that runs an http server, and uses the net package to determine and parse the IP address of the incoming request. With this build statement:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -a -ldflags '-s' .
```

And this preamble in my program:

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/blog/content/context/userip"

    "github.com/oschwald/maxminddb-golang"
)
```

This worked building with go 1.3, producing a statically linked program, but is not working with go 1.4.2. The build succeeds, but the program is not statically linked.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More searching turned up [this thread in the golang issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9344) about being unable to statically link a program that imports the `net` package due to changes between 1.3 and 1.4.

Reading down I found [this workaround suggested by ianlancetaylor](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9344#issuecomment-69944514) to use the `-installsuffix` switch to specify `cgo`. This made my build statement:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-s' .
```

Which worked for me. Build succeeded and produced a statically linked program.